# CentOS: Copy directory to another directory

Tags: linux, centos, copy, cp

I'm working with a CentOS server. I have a folder named `test` located in `/home/server/folder/test`. I need to copy the directory `test` to `/home/server/`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
cp -r /home/server/folder/test /home/server/
```

Comment: if i need to copy Only all files in `test` directory(without test directory) to `/home/server/`. how to ?

Comment: `cp -r /home/server/folder/test/* /home/server/`

Comment: is there any difference in using -R in here ?

Comment: If there's a directory inside `test` directory, yes there is a difference.

Comment: Hey @BaTmaN, check my answer below. I think that might work for your case!

Answer (score 27):

To copy all files, including hidden files use:

```
cp -r /home/server/folder/test/. /home/server/
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Copying files no problem, copying files and hidden files was an elusive problem. +1

Comment: This is the only way thats working for me. The * doesn't work!

Comment: In my case, in order to save time, I specify the current directory like this: `$ cp -r ./Origin/. ./Destination/`

Answer (score 17):

As I understand, you want to recursively copy test directory into `/home/server/` path...

This can be done as:

```
-cp -rf /home/server/folder/test/* /home/server/
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work for me. "No such file or directory" when adding the `*`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
cp -r /home/server/folder/test/. /home/server
```

Answer (score 1):

For copy directory use following command

```
cp -r source    Destination
```

For example

```
cp -r  /home/hasan   /opt
```

For copy file use command without -r

```
cp   /home/file    /home/hasan/
```